# Touchpad needs to be disabled in sony vaio E Series

Tags: windows-7, touchpad, sony-vaio

The touchpad is creating nuisance while typing so I want to disable it, but it is not happening I also installed this Vaio control centre software, but it also doesn't have that option.

Later I tried this →

[image],

but it still doesnt have the option to disable the touch pad.

Comment: On some Vaio models you can disable the touchpad by pressing Fn + F1

Comment: tied sir already, but it dodnt worked may be something is not installed.

Comment: Have a look at all the stuff this [site](http://www.instructables.com/id/Disable-Touchpad-on-Sony-Vaio-Laptop-after-Clean-W/) says is necessary to install from Sony in order to get that Enable check box to appear in the Viao Control Center

Comment: Actually, these two things are required → Make sure u have installed Sony utility, shared library. once these two things are fixed the options appears in Vaio Control centre. Even the Fn + F1 things start working.